# 2 way communication using HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tcp, websocket, webserver

I've been looking for a while for a simple solution to what seems like a relatively simple problem, but I just cannot for the life of me manage to find it.

So here is what I am trying to do:

1. Server (Hosting an HTML file, Has a variable, x, which is a javascript variable)
2. Server is running on my local network (192.168.x.x, with no security)
3. Client, PC, has access to SSH, Telnet, whatever, and wants to communicate over TCP/IP

So my question is this: How can I get the client to send a value, over TCP/IP, to the server, changing the value of that variable?

I can see that there are rather complex ways to do this, using websockets, sockJS, and other complex solutions, but if anyone knows of a super simple way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks :)

Comment: websockets are as simple as you are going to get...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use sockets.  I'd recommend socket.io http://socket.io/